# Possible to do subselect in Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets, subquery, google-query-language

I have the following data in the `movies` data range:

[image]

I would like to do a `subselect` to get the highest-grossing movie for that director. I can do it by adding a new column like this:

[image]

Note that I've used the hacky 'nested-query' notation to remove the header row and just return a single scalar value:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(movies, "SELECT MAX(C) WHERE A='"&A2&"' GROUP BY A", 0), "SELECT * OFFSET 1", 0)
```

However, I was wondering if I could just do a single query on the director|movie|boxoffice columns with a subselect within the query statement, I suppose it would come out to something like:

```
=QUERY(movies, "SELECT A, B, C, (SELECT MAX(C) WHERE A='"&A2&"' GROUP BY A)", 0)
```

I believe the answer to this is a straight 'no', but I was curious if there's any sort of sub-query composability within the google sheets query language, or if I just need to sort of figure out workarounds here?

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: You are right the answer to this is a straight "no".

Comment: everything is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SORT(A2:C, 3, ), 3, )))
```

[image]

or whole:

```
=INDEX({A1:C, {"highestgrossing"; IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SORT(A2:C, 3, ), 3, ))}})
```

[image]

Comment: yes of course it's possible! Very creative approach. I just meant possible to do "within a single `QUERY(...)`.